# htaccess file altered by itself

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an issue that I have had before but thought I have seen the last of it. I use this code in my htaccess file to run php on .html pages on my website.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php .html
```

For some unknown reason, without me knowing, # is added to this line like

```
# AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php .html
```

This obviously breaks my site. When i contact my hosting company they just say I must have done it. My response is why would I break my own site. They have never given me a proper reason for it. I may happen twice a year as if caused by some server update. I used shared hosting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When is the bash added?

Comment: I am not 100% as I dont look at the site everyday. I happened to check it today and saw the problem. To fix it i just reove the hash. It seems to be random times maybe 2 or 3 times a year. tks

Comment: Quite possibly they (hosters) have a script that looks for hinky `.htaccess` files. The `.html` would class as hinky as its not usual to pass .html files through the PHP interpreter, in fact its mormally unnecessary if the site is well designed

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the whole .htaccess file? Make sure you have [mod_mime](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html) enabled and restart apache2 after you applied the changes (taking into account you have a shared hosting plan I believe you have to ask Customer Service to do that). Probably this is due to the missing module.

Possible duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/553855/how-to-enable-mod-mime-on-apache2) question.

Comment: this is all i have in the access file - AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php .html i use a hosting company and dont know how to restart apache

Comment: Have you contacted them? They must be able to do something, especially enabling this module. I had a similar issue with `mod_security` and got solved just by enabling the module.